# How to fix warped/distorted and cut-out images in HTML canvas object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

> I'm trying to cut out the largest possible square area of an image with the draw image function of a canvas object in HTML5 with JavaScript. Also, the cut-out area should be the center of the original image.

(I am also rendering a watermark on top of the image.)

This works fine without trying to cut out the center of the image, but whenever I tried to do this, the result gets warped.

> This is the [warped image](http://prntscr.com/nbhfcz)
>   and this [how the original looks like](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/46/1c/01/461c0133da95e315cd4e245f79219ec0.jpg)

An example for the warped image is also given in the code snippet below!

To cut out a part of an image, *you have to declare two coordinates P1 and P2* with for each 2 variables.

The coordinate system is [like this](http://prntscr.com/nbhmie) (i think):

**To calculate P1 and P2 I am using:**

*imagewidth < imageheight*

```
P1:
----
x1 = 0
y1 = (imageheight / 2) - (imagewidth / 2)
// if I'm replacing y1 with 0, it wont get warped
// but it will cut out the top of the image

and

P2:
----
x2 = imagewidth
y2 = y1 + imagewidth
```

*imagewidth > imageheight*

```
P1:
----
x1 = (imagewidth / 2) - (imageheight / 2)
y1 = 0
// if I'm replacing x1 with 0, it wont get warped
// but it will cut out the most left part of the image

and

P2:
----
x2 = x1 + imageheight
y2 = imageheight
```

## Here is my code:

basically it writes into this object:

```html
<div id="buy_imagelist" class=imagelist></div>
```

javascript:

```py
var numbers = ["images/test_images/bluefireoly-2.jpg"];
var txt = "";
var numCanvas = 0;

for(var src in numbers) {
    numCanvas++;
}

var i = 0;
for(var src in numbers) {
    txt = txt + '<canvas class=imagelistsingle style=padding:7px id=myCanvas' + i + ' width="300" height="300"></canvas>';
    i++;
}

document.getElementById('buy_imagelist').innerHTML = txt;
var imageNumber_canvas = 0;

numbers.forEach(myFunction);

function myFunction(value, index, array) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas' + imageNumber_canvas);
    if(canvas == null) {
        window.alert("Error - Images could not be loaded");
    }
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    function loadImages(imagelist, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;

        for(var src in imagelist) {
            numImages++;
        }

        for(var src in imagelist) {

            images[src] = new Image();
            images[src].onload = function() {
                if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
                    callback(images);
                }
            };
            images[src].src = imagelist[src];

        }

    }

    var imagelist = {
        testimage: value,
        wasserzeichen: "images/wasserzeichen/wasserzeichen_1.png"
    };

    loadImages(imagelist, function(images) {

        var testimage = images.testimage;

        var imagewidth = testimage.naturalWidth;
        var imageheight = testimage.naturalHeight;

        var x1 = 0;
        var y1 = 0;
        var x2 = imagewidth;
        var y2 = imageheight;

        if(imagewidth !== imageheight) {

            if(imageheight < imagewidth) {

                x1 = (imagewidth / 2) - (imageheight / 2);
                y1 = 0;

                x2 = x1 + imageheight;
                y2 = imageheight;

            } else {

                x1 = 0;
                y1 = (imageheight / 2) - (imagewidth / 2);

                x2 = imagewidth;
                y2 = y1 + imagewidth;

            }

        }

        context.drawImage(testimage, x1, y1, x2, y2, 0, 0, 300, 300);
        context.drawImage(images.wasserzeichen, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    });

    imageNumber_canvas++;

}
```

As expected, this works fine for square images.

The error must be somewhere here (expecially where I marked it with "//!")

```
var testimage = images.testimage;

var imagewidth = testimage.naturalWidth;
var imageheight = testimage.naturalHeight;

var x1 = 0;
var y1 = 0;
var x2 = imagewidth;
var y2 = imageheight;

if(imagewidth !== imageheight) {

    if(imageheight < imagewidth) {

        x1 = (imagewidth / 2) - (imageheight / 2); //!
        y1 = 0;

        x2 = x1 + imageheight;
        y2 = imageheight;

    } else {

        x1 = 0;
        y1 = (imageheight / 2) - (imagewidth / 2); //!

        x2 = imagewidth;
        y2 = y1 + imagewidth;

    }

}

context.drawImage(testimage, x1, y1, x2, y2, 0, 0, 300, 300);
context.drawImage(images.wasserzeichen, 0, 0, 300, 300);
```

> For the non-square image given above (1028x1920) (width < height)
>
> > -> y1 = 446 
> >     -> so y2 = 446 + 1028 = 1474
> >
> > > so y1 > 0 
> > >       so y2 < height 
> > >       **->** cut-out square should fit in the original image

**Use this code to try it out for yourself:**
(click on "full page" to see the image)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="buy_imagelist" class=imagelist></div>

  <script>
    var numbers = ["https://i.pinimg.com/originals/46/1c/01/461c0133da95e315cd4e245f79219ec0.jpg"];
    var txt = "";
    var numCanvas = 0;

    for (var src in numbers) {
      numCanvas++;
    }

    var i = 0;
    for (var src in numbers) {
      txt = txt + '<canvas class=imagelistsingle style=padding:7px id=myCanvas' + i + ' width="300" height="300"></canvas>';
      i++;
    }

    document.getElementById('buy_imagelist').innerHTML = txt;
    var imageNumber_canvas = 0;

    numbers.forEach(myFunction);

    function myFunction(value, index, array) {

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas' + imageNumber_canvas);
      if (canvas == null) {
        window.alert("Error - Images could not be loaded");
      }
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      function loadImages(imagelist, callback) {
        var images = {};
        var loadedImages = 0;
        var numImages = 0;

        for (var src in imagelist) {
          numImages++;
        }

        for (var src in imagelist) {

          images[src] = new Image();
          images[src].onload = function() {
            if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
              callback(images);
            }
          };
          images[src].src = imagelist[src];

        }

      }

      var imagelist = {
        testimage: value
      };

      loadImages(imagelist, function(images) {

        var testimage = images.testimage;

        var imagewidth = testimage.naturalWidth;
        var imageheight = testimage.naturalHeight;

        var x1 = 0;
        var y1 = 0;
        var x2 = imagewidth;
        var y2 = imageheight;

        if (imagewidth !== imageheight) {

          if (imageheight < imagewidth) {

            x1 = (imagewidth / 2) - (imageheight / 2);
            y1 = 0;

            x2 = x1 + imageheight;
            y2 = imageheight;

          } else {

            x1 = 0;
            y1 = (imageheight / 2) - (imagewidth / 2);

            x2 = imagewidth;
            y2 = y1 + imagewidth;

          }

        }

        context.drawImage(testimage, x1, y1, x2, y2, 0, 0, 300, 300);

      });

      imageNumber_canvas++;

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4th and 5th argument of the `drawImage` method are `width` and `height`, not `x2` and `y2`.

The documentation on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) uses this in the first example

```
ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
```

with the explanation

> The source image is taken from the coordinates (33, 71), with a width of 104 and a height of 124. It is drawn to the canvas at (21, 20), where it is given a width of 87 and a height of 104.

**tl;dr**

You have to provide the width/height of the cutout image, not the coordinates of the bottom right corner:

```
context.drawImage(testimage, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1, 0, 0, 300, 300);
```